# How to join the same table twice on a code

Tags: sql, left-join

```
Select Production.ProductCategory.Name,
    Production.ProductSubcategory.Name,
    Production.ProductModel.Name,
    Production.Product.ProductNumber,
    Production.Product.Name,
    Sales.SalesOrderDetail.OrderQty,
    (sales.SalesOrderDetail.OrderQty * Production.Product.StandardCost) AS 'Cost', 
    Sales.SalesOrderDetail.LineTotal AS 'Revenue',Max('Revenue')-Min('Cost') AS Profit,
    ((Profit/(sales.SalesOrderDetail.OrderQty * Production.Product.StandardCost))*100) AS 'Markup_Percentage'
From Sales.SalesOrderDetail
Left Join Production.Product ON Product.ProductSubcategoryID = SalesOrderDetail.ProductID 
Left Join Production.ProductSubcategory ON Production.ProductSubcategory.Name = Production.Product.ProductSubcategoryID
Left join Production.ProductCategory ON Production.ProductCategory.ProductCategoryID = Production.ProductSubcategory.Name
Left Join Production.ProductModel ON ProductModel.Name = SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID
Left join Production.Product ON Production.Product.Name = Production.ProductModel.Name
Order by Max('Revenue')-Min('Cost') asc;
```

I am doing an assignment and I need to basically join multiple tables but my problem is that I tried joining the product table twice because of a aliases table but it keeps popping up with a message of:

> Msg 1013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> The objects "Production.Product" and "Production.Product" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: Please show the complete error message. And whats an "allie table"?

Comment: And I highly recommend the use of table aliases as they make your query much clearer.

Comment: You have reference `Production.Product` twice in the joins without an alias

Comment: Using aliases will solve many problems including the one you are asking about.

Comment: Also noticed that you have aggregate function `Max()`  and `Min()` without any `GROUP BY`

Comment: And also avoid 3 part naming like `Production.Product.Name` [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/)

Comment: Oh okay thank you! An i used the three part because it will only work if I do use the three part.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0):

You should use an **alias** for each of the objects in the query:

```
Select pc.Name,
    ps.Name,
    pm.Name,
    p.ProductNumber,
    p.Name,
    sod.OrderQty,
    (sod.OrderQty * p.StandardCost) AS "Cost", 
    sod.LineTotal AS "Revenue",
    Max(sod.LineTotal)-Min(sod.ORderQty*p.StandardCost) AS Profit,
    (((Max(sod.LineTotal)-Min(sod.ORderQty*p.StandardCost))/(sod.OrderQty * p.StandardCost))*100) AS "Markup_Percentage"
From Sales.SalesOrderDetail sod
Left Join Production.Product p ON p.ProductSubcategoryID = sod.ProductID 
Left Join Production.ProductSubcategory ps ON ps.Name = p.ProductSubcategoryID
Left join Production.ProductCategory pc ON pc.ProductCategoryID = ps.Name
Left Join Production.ProductModel pm ON pm.Name = sod.SalesOrderID
Left join Production.Product p2 ON p2.Name = pm.Name
Order by Max(sod.LineTotal)-Min(sod.OrderQty * p.StandardCost) asc;
```

Since `Production.Product` was used twice, I wasn't sure which instance of the table was referred to in the `SELECT` clause and had to guess... which should explain why this was an error: the query was ambiguous.

Now, the query is no longer ambiguous, but since I didn't know which instance of the table was intended where I just used the first instance of the `Product` table, which is probably wrong in a few places.

As a general rule you should use aliases for pretty much every query with at least two tables.

Separately, I don't think you're allowed to use `MAX()` and `MIN()` in a query like this without a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I added a group by and used your query but i also keep getting the message Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Bib-Shorts' to data type int.

Comment: I added a group by and used your query but i also keep getting the message Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Bib-Shorts' to data type int.